# How to go through a complex object formatting the given required fields using a function passed by parameter?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, logic

I'm trying to create a function that goes through a complex object formatting the given fields in an array.

The function must receive the object that must be formatted, then the next parameter is an array with the attributes that must be formatted and finally the last function receives the function that will format the value of the field.

The function must return the object in it's original structure.

my code until now:

```js
const formatFields = (obj = {}) => (fieldsToFormat = []) => (formatFunction = () => {}) => {
   let newObj = { ...obj };
   for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) formatFields(v)(fieldsToFormat)(formatFunction);
      if (fieldsToFormat.includes(k)) newObj = { ...newObj, [k]: formatFunction(v) };
      else newObj = { ...newObj, [k]: v };
   }
   return newObj;
}

const toMoney = (num) => '$' + num;

const obj = { 
    totalAmount: 83.24,
    quoteItems: 
       [ { max: '1',
           code: '1',
           quantity: 1,
           unitPrice: 23.21,
           totalPrice: 23.21,
           description: 'test' 
         },{ 
           max: '3',
           code: '2',
           quantity: 3,
           unitPrice: 20.01,
           totalPrice: 60.03,
           description: 'test2' 
       } ],
};

const priceFormatAttributes = [
    'unitPrice', 
    'totalPrice', 
    'totalAmount'
];

console.log(formatFields(obj)(priceFormatAttributes)(toMoney));
```

The nested objects are not being formatted!

I know this is a logical problem... it's being challenging and I can't move on.

I think that the recursion is wrong but I can't see why!

if anyone has an idea how to solve this in another way it is also welcome.

Comment: First off, `formatFields` returns an Object, so how would you execute a Object. You can't.

Comment: Why the complicated function returns function thing? I can't see why `formatFields` can't just have three parameters?

Comment: @Dominik there is no HOC in here just closures...

Comment: What is your actual goal? Object properties are about the easiest thing to access already. Don't make things more complicated that they have to be.

Comment: @EugenSunic you're right. I edited the comment. On line 4 you're not returning the result of `formatFields` into your result which is where the recursion breaks

Comment: the three parameter i made to make it functional and use in pipes for example

Comment: Why don't you show the xpected output, this aint really helpful at least to me...+1 for the problem

Comment: i want the function puts the "$" symbol before the value of the attribute named in array priceFormatAttributes in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure what the expected output is I would try this:

```js
const formatFields = (obj = {}) => (fieldsToFormat = []) => (formatFunction = () => {}) => {
    let newObj = { ...obj }; // clone object to prevent changing the original object
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) { // gotta deal with arrays too unless you want to change them all into objects
        newObj = [ ...obj ];
    }

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (Array.isArray(newObj)) {
            newObj.splice(key - 1, 1); // remove the previous it
            newObj.push(formatFields(value)(fieldsToFormat)(formatFunction));
        }
        else if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            newObj = { ...newObj, [key]: formatFields(value)(fieldsToFormat)(formatFunction) };
        }
        else if (fieldsToFormat.includes(key)) {
            newObj[key] = formatFunction(value)
        }
        else newObj = { ...newObj, [key]: value };
    }

    return newObj;
}

const toMoney = (num) => {
    return '$' + num;
}

const obj = {
    totalAmount: 83.24,
    quoteItems: [
        {
            max: '1',
            code: '1',
            quantity: 1,
            unitPrice: 23.21,
            totalPrice: 23.21,
            description: 'test',
        },
        {
            max: '3',
            code: '2',
            quantity: 3,
            unitPrice: 20.01,
            totalPrice: 60.03,
            description: 'test2',
        }
    ],
};

const priceFormatAttributes = [
    'unitPrice',
    'totalPrice',
    'totalAmount',
];

console.log(formatFields(obj)(priceFormatAttributes)(toMoney));
```

This outputs:

```
{
  totalAmount: '$83.24',
  quoteItems: [
    {
      max: '1',
      code: '1',
      quantity: 1,
      unitPrice: '$23.21',
      totalPrice: '$23.21',
      description: 'test'
    },
    {
      max: '3',
      code: '2',
      quantity: 3,
      unitPrice: '$20.01',
      totalPrice: '$60.03',
      description: 'test2'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it is formatting but changes the object format... almost there... the attributes of one object of the array is overoverwriting the formated fields that are out of object format... I need that the function keeps the object strucutre.

Comment: Maybe you edit your question a bit to include all these bits and I'll look at it again later

Comment: I edited my my answer. Let me know if this is what you wanted.